# C++ should I use virtual methods?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions

Let me start by telling that I understand how virtual methods work (polymorphism, late-binding, vtables).

My question is whether or not I should make my method virtual. I will exemplify my dilemma on a specific case, but any general guidelines will be welcomed too.

The context:

I am creating a library. In this library I have a class `CallStack` that captures a call stack and then offers vector-like access to the captured stack frames. The capture is done by a `protected` method `CaptureStack`. This method could be redefined in a derived class, if the users of the library wish to implement another way to capture the stack. Just to be clear, the discussion to make the method `virtual` applies only to some methods that I know can be redefined in a derived class (in this case `CaptureStack` and the `destructor`), not to all the class methods.

Throughout my library I use `CallStack` objects, but never exposed as pointers or reference parameters, thus making `virtual` not needed considering only the use of my library.

And I cannot think of a case when someone would want to use `CallStack` as pointer or reference to implement polymorphism. If someone wants to derive `CallStack` and redefine `CaptureStack` I think just using the derived class object will suffice.

Now just because I cannot think polymorphism will be needed, should I not use `virtual` methods, or should I use `virtual` regardless just because a method can be redefined.

---

Example how `CallStack` can be used outside my library:

```
if (error) {
  CallStack call_stack; // the constructor calls CaptureStack
  for (const auto &stack_frame : call_stack) {
    cout << stack_frame << endl;
  }
}
```

A derived class, that redefines `CaptureStack` could be use in the same manner, not needing polymorphism:

```
if (error) {
  // since this is not a CallStack pointer / reference, virtual would not be needed.
  DerivedCallStack d_call_stack; 
  for (const auto &stack_frame : d_call_stack) {
    cout << stack_frame << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Virtual functions are expensve (from the performance point of view), but you can't always do things without them. On the other hand, C++ is not only a OOP language, and it provides many other features/tools to do this kind of things (Parametric polymorphism through templates, policy based designs, etc). The point is: **C++ is not limited to runtime polymorphism only, as other "high level" OOP languages are, like Java.** To have polymorphic behaviour you don't need to fall into virtual functions.

Comment: A general hint: unless You arent using special design patterns, you perhaps really do not need virtual or pure virtual methods. Framework designera may also want to use  them. I for myself really only use virtual or pure virtual methods only, when i design software architecture, which benefits from overriding super methods. In plain application development i avoid this. Hope, this helps a bit.

Comment: @icbytes even in large software architectures, virtual functions are not necessary. Policy/component based designs instead of large OOP class booooom-prone hierarchies are possible, used, and don't rely on virtual methods.

Comment: @Manu343726 I don't know where you get the idea that virtual functions are expensive.  They're generally the cheapest way of getting the functionality you need.

Comment: @Manu343726 : I agree with James. The performance impact of virtual functions is negligible unless you're calling it extremely frequently.

Comment: @JamesKanze Consider a high performance related context (In normal contexts I'm not going to be worried about the negligible performance difference between an indirect function call [Function pointers or virtual functions]). The point of virtual functions is that (without profiling/usage data) the compiler is not capable of inline the virtual functions. Now compare that with a CRTP approach, where everything could be inlined. No branches, no stalls, better performance. But, as I said, for high performance situations.

Comment: The `virtual` functions are expensive because in order to call them, you need to go and fetch the object from the memory, look at the address of the function, and then go and run that address, instead of just knowing where to call when you are supposed to run the function. I agree that they are really expensive.

Comment: @adrin Measurements, at least on Intel processors and Sparcs, show the opposite.  They aren't particularly expensive.  (I've heard that on HP's PA, they are.)  And of course, in contexts where the performance is critical, you'll use cross-module optimization with profiler output, which does allow inlining.  (For that matter, in the context the OP describes, just about any compiler will be capable of inlining the virtual function calls.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Consider this benchmarks: http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/12/the-cost-of-dynamic-virtual-calls-vs.-static-crtp-dispatch-in-c-eli-benders That's not a negligible difference I think. As I said, inlining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deciding whether you need a `virtual` function or not, you need to see if deriving and overriding the function changes the expected behavior/functionality of other functions that you're implementing now or not.

If you are relying on the implementation of that particular function in your other processes of the same class, like another function of the same class, then you might want to have the function as virtual. But if you know what the function is supposed to do in your parent class, and you don't want anybody to change it as far as you're concerned, then it's not a `virtual` function.

Or as another example, imagine somebody derives a class from you implementation, overrides a function, and passes that object as casted to the parent class to one of your own implemented functions/classes. Would you prefer to have your original implementation of the function or you want them to have you use their own overriden implementation? If the latter is the case, then you should go for `virtual`, unless not.

Answer (score 2):

If your library saves the call stack during the constructor then you **cannot** use virtual methods.

This is C++. One thing people often get wrong when coming to C++ from another language is using virtual methods in constructors. This never works as planned.

C++ sets the virtual function table during each constructor call. That means that functions are **never** virtual when called from the constructor. The virtual method always points to the current class being constructed.

So even if you did use a virtual method to capture the stack the constructor code would always call the base class method.

To make it work you'd need to take the call out of the constructor and use something like:

```
CallStack *stack = new DerivedStack;
stack.CaptureStack();
```

None of your code examples show a good reason to make CaptureStack virtual.

Comment: Following your notes on constructors and virtual methods, I have done some testing: The base constructor calls the method. I looks like: if in the derived constructor the method is called, the derived method will be called regardless of the `virtualness` of the base method. If the derived constructor doesn't call the method, the base method will be called (in the base constructor) regardless of the `virtualness` of the method. Are my observations correct?

Comment: For the specific example with the method being called from the constructor, your answer is spot on, thank you. However, I will accept another answer that gives more general guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me where `CallStack` is being called.  From
your examples, it looks like you're using the template method
pattern, in which the basic functionality is implemented in the
base class, but customized by means of virtual functions
(normally private, not protected) which are provided by the
derived class.  In this case (as Peter Bloomfield points out),
the functions must be virtual, since they will be called from
within a member function of the base class; thus, with a static
type of `CallStack`.  However: if I understand your examples
correctly, the call to `CallStack` will be in the constructor.
This will not work, as during construction of `CallStack`, the
dynamic type of the object is `CallStack`, and not
`DerivedCallStack`, and virtual function calls will resolve to
`CallStack`.

In such a case, for the use cases you describe, a solution using
templates may be more appropriate.  Or even...  The name of the
class is clear.  I can't think of any reasonable case where
different instances should have different means of capturing the
call stack *in a single program*.  Which suggests that link time
resolution of the type might be appropriate.  (I use the
compilation firewall idiom and link time resolution in my own
`StackTrace` class.)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is whether or not I should make my method virtual. I will exemplify my dilemma on a specific case, but any general guidelines will be welcomed too.

Some guidelines:

- if you are unsure, you should not do it. Lots of people will tell you that your code should be easily extensible (and as such, virtual), but in practice, most extensible code is never extended, unless you make a library that will be used heavily (see YAGNI principle).
- you can use encapsulation in place of inheritance and type polymorphism (templates) as an alternative to class hierarchies in many cases (e.g. std::string and std::wstring are not two concrete implementations of a base string class and they are not inheritable at all).
- if (when you are designing your code/public interfaces) you realize you have more than one class that "is an" implementation of another classes' interface, then you should use virtual functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should almost certainly declare the method as `virtual`.

The first reason is that anything in your base class which calls `CaptureStack` will be doing so through a base class pointer (i.e. the local `this` pointer). It will therefore call the base class version of the function, even though a derived class masks it.

Consider the following example:

```
class Parent
{
public:
    void callFoo()
    {
        foo();
    }

    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Parent::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Child::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Child obj;
    obj.callFoo();
    return 0;
}
```

The client code using the class is only ever using a derived object (not a base class pointer etc.). However, it's the base class version of `foo()` that actually gets called. The only way to resolve that is to make `foo()` virtual.

The second reason is simply one of correct design. If the purpose of the derived class function is to *override* rather than *mask* the original, then it should probably do so unless there is a specific reason otherwise (such as performance concerns). If you don't do that, you're inviting bugs and mistakes in future, because the class may not act as expected.